# zip list with more than 2 values to dict python

Tags: python

I have this two lists:

```
values = ['0.7%', '11.1%', '8.7%']
key = ['NA']
```

which I want to zip to dict(ie. Keys and value). so that output will look like this:

```
{'NA': '0.7%', '11.1%', '8.7%'}
```

here is my current code:

```
values = ['0.7%', '11.1%', '8.7%']
key = ['NA']

joiner = dict(zip(key, values))
print(joiner)
```

currrent output:

```
{'NA': '0.7%'}
```

Comment: `{'NA': '0.7%', '11.1%', '8.7%'}` is not a valid dict. What output do you want? Note: you probably want a list of values, but you need to write it correctly in that case.

Comment: ok. how please.

Comment: `joiner  = {key[0]: values}` and the output will look like `{'NA': ['0.7%', '11.1%', '8.7%']}`

Comment: What output would you expect when you have more than 1 key?

Comment: The key is always one. I expect the output to look like this:   {'NA': '0.7%', '11.1%', '8.7%'}. BUt I learnt from @Paritosh that its invalid. Is there a better way to get this output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Completed:**

```
values = ['0.7%', '11.1%', '8.7%']
key = ['NA']

joiner = {f"{key[0]}": values}
print(joiner)
```

Comment: @Odinukweze here is answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
print({key[0]:' ,'.join(values)})
```